# Read data of specific column in text file C#

Tags: c#, file, text

I am new to C# and hoping you can help me. I have text file with data mad of rows and the columns are separated by tabs. See example below. My question: how can read the data from just column three.

```
739492  3   600 3   600
739493  20  4000    3   600
739494  3   600 3   600
739495  20  4000    3   600
739496  3   600 3   600
739497  20  4000    3   600
```

My current code reads the full line:

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyName);
    m_readFile = new StreamReader (assemblyDirectory + @"\" + "MyDataFile.txt");

    int counter = 1;
    string line;

    while ((line = m_readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(line);            
        counter++;
    }

    m_readFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: try `line.Split('\t')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string assemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyName);
    m_readFile = new StreamReader (assemblyDirectory + @"\" + "MyDataFile.txt");

    int counter = 1;
    string line;
    while ((line = m_readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string col = line.Split(' ')[2];
        MessageBox.Show(line);            
        counter++;
    }

    m_readFile.Close();
}
```

If your columns in text file are separated by TAB you need to use:

```
string col = line.Split('\t')[2];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome :) By the way, if you want, you can mark this as answer.

Comment: Thank you SeM. This answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((line = m_readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] columns = line.Split(',');
    //Now you can access the 3rd column of each line with column[2]           
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CsvHelper (http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
while( csv.Read() )
{
    var intField = csv.GetField<int>( 2 ); // index is 0 based
}
```