# Modify/replace Text in tab-base text file in C#

Tags: c#, string, text, replace

This question is a continuation of a past discussion [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958165/read-data-of-specific-column-in-text-file-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment59571637_35958165). So now I managed to read every line in my text file and also read the exact string in a certain column. My issue now is that I wish to modify a text value in say Column (4) of the tab-base file with another string value. 
For example, the original file is like this:

```
ID1 25  800 Low
ID2 25  700 Low
ID3 25  600 Low
```

I want to Change to:

```
ID1 25  800 High
ID2 25  700 High
ID3 25  600 High
```

… here is my full code. I appreciate your help.

```
string route = @"C:\MyFile.txt";
FileStream fileStream2 = new FileStream(route, FileMode.Open);

var m_readFile2 = new StreamReader(fileStream2);
var m_writeFile2 = new StreamWriter(fileStream2);

        string[] colArr1 = new string[100];
        string[] colArr2 = new string[100];
        string[] colArr3 = new string[100];
        string[] colArr4 = new string[100];
        int arrcount = 1;

        while ((line = m_readFile2.ReadLine()) != null)

        {

            string col1 = "";
            string col2 = "";
            string col3 = "";
            string col4 = "";

                col1 = line.Split('\t')[0];
                col2 = line.Split('\t')[1];
                col3 = line.Split('\t')[2];
                col4 = line.Split('\t')[3];

                colArr1[arrcount] = col1;
                colArr2[arrcount] = col2;
                colArr3[arrcount] = col3;
                colArr4[arrcount] = col4;    


                m_writeFile2.WriteLine("Serv" + arrcount  + "\t" + "25" + "\t" + "400" + "\t" + "High");
                arrcount = arrcount + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you split the lines into an array and put a new line back together:

```
        string source = @"D:\MyFile.txt";
        string destination = @"D:\MyFile2.txt";

        int columnToChange = 3;
        string newValueForColumn = "High";

        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream destinationStream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {

                using (StreamReader sourceReader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
                {

                    using (StreamWriter destinationWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationStream))
                    {
                        string oldLine = string.Empty;
                        while ((oldLine = sourceReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] values = oldLine.Split('\t');
                            StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
                            if (values.Length > columnToChange)
                            {
                                values[columnToChange] = newValueForColumn;
                                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    newLine.Append(values[i]);
                                    if (i + 1 < values.Length)
                                    {
                                        newLine.Append('\t');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newLine.Append(oldLine);
                            }

                            destinationWriter.WriteLine(newLine.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // File.Delete(source);
        File.Move(source, source + ".bak");
        File.Move(destination, source);
    }
```

Comment: `stringbuilder` is best option to append string

Comment: I have built the full new line in an array string. It is a simple text file. however, when I use WriteLine, the text file looks like this, not modified, but added extra lines:   
ServID1 25  800 Low
ServID2 25  700 Low
ServID3 25  600 LowServID1 25  800 High
ServID2 25  700 High

But I want it to modify the text not add extra lines :-(

Comment: True and understandable. As you are writing back to the same file. You should write all newLines into a new file and when completed you should close both files, delete the old one and rename the new one to the old name

Comment: Hi Thomas: So I cannot do read and modify a text file at the same time! Well...if this is true the s bit strange to me and not automated especially if that I will be modifying this text file more than 10 times! I want to try your suggest, would mind direct me with example on ho to delete the file and also rename a text file.... thank you

Comment: I edited my post and added the suggested implementation. I've also added usings to properly dispose all disposables after usage. Additionally I've extracted the column to replace and the new value for the column, so that you can easily put that into a Method.

Answer (score 1):

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(route);

text = text.Replace("Low", "High");

File.WriteAllText(route, text);
```

Comment: I fear that's not fullfilling all needs. What if a different column contains "Low" as well. That shouldn't be replaced. I think your approach is "to simple and stupid" ;-)

Comment: @ThomasVoß - Everything can be... However, the provided code exactly meets the requirements. If the requirements are other - there will be another code. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Thank you for reminding me on basic principles. You're totally right. So now there is a solution for both requirements...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Works fine Thomas Voß  - I've just added a line to ensure that Column Header is 
    //also not changed
    string source = @"D:\MyFile.txt";
    string destination = @"D:\MyFile2.txt";

    int columnToChange = 3;
    string newValueForColumn = "High";

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FileStream destinationStream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {

            using (StreamReader sourceReader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
            {

                using (StreamWriter destinationWriter = new StreamWriter(destinationStream))
                {
                    string oldLine = string.Empty;
                    while ((oldLine = sourceReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] values = oldLine.Split('\t');
                        StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
                        if (values.Length > columnToChange)
                        {
                            if (values[columnToChange] != "ColumnHeaderName")
                            {
                               values[columnToChange] = newValueForColumn;
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                            {
                                newLine.Append(values[i]);
                                if (i + 1 < values.Length)
                                {
                                    newLine.Append('\t');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newLine.Append(oldLine);
                        }

                        destinationWriter.WriteLine(newLine.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // File.Delete(source);
    File.Move(source, source + ".bak");
    File.Move(destination, source);
}
```